# AVD Manager Nexus 5_API_22_X86

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I'm getting error in this. Help me fix it. I already installed the Intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer)

ERROR MESSAGE-

> Cannot launch AVD emulator.
>   Output:
>   emulator error: x86 emulation currently requires accelaration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and unusable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some problem in installing HAXM.

Have you followed these steps?

Steps for using Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager

1.Start the Android SDK Manager, select Extras and then select Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager.(you have done this)

2.Run [sdk]/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe

and follow the instructions and complete installation(this step may be left).

Comment: I Selected Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAMX Installer) and install it. it still has a error

Comment: There is no Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager in the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Check in SDK Manager if you have all the software installed (Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) ).

Check if you have "Hardware Virtualization" enabled in your BIOS (if not, enable it).

Then, go to your Android SDK folder. Go to Extras>Intel>Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager. Install "intelhaxm-android.exe"

Try now.

Check this Intel tutorial https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Your computer could not be compatible with this technology. In this situation, you have to run your emulator with ARM.

I hope this will help you :D